# Why is `(,x) a shorthand for (cons x '())?

Tags: scheme, quasiquotes, backquote, reasoned-schemer

I'm told that:  `` `(,x) `` is a shorthand for `(cons x '())`.

I'm a bit confused because that's not documented anywhere.

Also if that is the case, what does  `` `(((pea)) ,q) `` evaluate to?

And why is `pea` wrapped in two sets of parens?

Comment: See `quasiquote` and `unquote` for documentation.

Comment: I can find a bunch of stuff about that but it's not like there's an official documentation for either of those somewhere, is there?

Comment: @Alper The Scheme standards are available online; e.g. [quasiquotation](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-14.html#node_sec_11.17) in R6RS.

Comment: The language of _The Reasoned Schemer_ is not Scheme, but istm knowledge of Scheme is assumed; the [TSPL index](http://cisco.github.io/ChezScheme/csug9.5/csug_1.html) is useful for online lookup ([find quasiquote => TSPL p142](https://scheme.com/tspl4/objects.html#./objects:s5)). [Racket](https://docs.racket-lang.org/minikanren/index.html) [documents](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/qq.html) may also be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
`(thing1 thing2 thing3 ...)
```

is roughly equivalent to

```
(list `thing1 `thing2 `thing3 ...)
```

When an expression inside backticks is preceded by a comma, that cancels out the backtick, so

```
`(,x)
```

is equivalent to

```
(list x)
```

Since a list is a chain of pairs whose last cdr is the empty list, this is equivalent to

```
(cons x '())
```

In your second example

```
`(((pea)) ,q)
```

is equivalent to

```
(list '((pea)) q)
```

Basically, when you use backquote, you can treat it like an ordinary quoted expression, except that `,` "unquotes" the subexpression that follows it. So you convert it to calls to `list` and `cons` with the non-comma expressions quoted, and the comma expressions *not* quoted.

As for why it has two sets of parentheses, that depends on how this data is being used. They needed `pea` to be nested 2 levels deep for some reason.